# Get SQL xml attribute value using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL function that takes a variable called `attribute`, which is the xml attribute I want to get the value from. `xmlPath` is the full XML string.

My xml looks like this:

```
<EventSpecificData>
  <Keyword>
    <Word>myWord</Word>
    <Occurences>1</Occurences>
    <Context>context</Context>
  </Keyword>
</EventSpecificData>
```

I want to get the value for `<Word>`, so I pass in `/Keyword/Word` and set a variable to:

```
set @value = @xmlPath.value('(/EventSpecificData/@attribute)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

However, I don't think @attribute is actually inserting the variables string. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that - the SQL XQuery works with literal strings quite often, and most of the time, they cannot be replaced with SQL variables....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are a couple of solutions for you.

Sample data:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = 
'<EventSpecificData>
  <Keyword>
    <Word>myWord</Word>
    <Occurences>1</Occurences>
    <Context>context</Context>
  </Keyword>
</EventSpecificData>'
```

Get the first value from node named Word regardless of parents. Use `//` to do a deep search and use `local-name()` to match node name.

```
declare @Attribute varchar(max)

set @Attribute = 'Word'
select @xml.value('(//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@Attribute")])[1]',  'varchar(max)')
```

Provide parent node name and attribute in separate variables using `local-name()` in two levels.

```
declare @Node varchar(max)
declare @Attribute varchar(max)

set @Attribute = 'Word'
set @Node = 'Keyword'
select @xml.value('(/EventSpecificData
                    /*[local-name() = sql:variable("@Node")]
                    /*[local-name() = sql:variable("@Attribute")])[1]',  'varchar(max)')
```

Since the parameter to `nodes` have to be a string literal it invites to use dynamic sql to solve this. It could look something like this to make it work with your original variable content.

```
set @Attribute = 'Keyword/Word'
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'select @xml.value(''(/EventSpecificData/'+@Attribute+')[1]'', ''varchar(max)'')'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@xml xml', @xml
```

**But** you should be aware of that if you use this you are wide open to SQL Injection attacks. Some devious end-user might come up with a attribute string that looks like this:

```
set @Attribute = 'Keyword/Word)[1]'', ''varchar(max)'') select @@version --'
```

Executing the dynamic SQL with that will give you two result sets. The `select @@version` is just there to show some harmless code but it might be much worse stuff in there.

You can use `quotename()` to prevent the SQL injection attack. It will at least prevent the attempt made by me.

```
set @Attribute = 'Keyword/Word'
set @SQL = 'select @xml.value('+quotename('(/EventSpecificData/'+@Attribute+')[1]', '''')+', ''varchar(max)'')'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@xml xml', @xml
```

Is the last version using `quotename()`safe? Have a look at this article by Erland Sommarskog [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Quote:

> So with quotename() and quotestring(), do we have as good protection
>   against SQL injection as we have with parameterised commands? Maybe. I
>   don't know of any way to inject SQL that slips through quotename() or
>   quotestring(). Nevertheless, you are interpolating user input into the
>   SQL string, whereas with parameterised commands, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the string.

```
set @value = @xmlPath.value('(/EventSpecificData/' + @attribute + ')[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

Updated answer:

Let's try CASE'ing the operation.

```
SELECT @value = CASE @attribute
        WHEN 'word' THEN [word]
        WHEN 'occurrence' THEN [occurrence]
        WHEN 'context' THEN [context]
        END AS [value]
FROM
(
    SELECT x.u.value('(/EventSpecificData/Keyword/Word)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [word]
        , x.u.value('(/EventSpecificData/Keyword/Occurrence)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [word]
        , x.u.value('(/EventSpecificData/Keyword/Context)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [word]
    FROM @xmlPath.nodes('/EventSpecificData') x(u)
) a
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I do this, I get the Message "The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal." since the first argument is an XQuery.

Comment: @user1200083: that error message says it all - you must have a string literal - you cannot have a variable.

Comment: Ok, so I can use and sql variable in the literal like this: select xmlPath.value('(*/*[local-name()=sql:variable("attribute1")])[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') assuming that attribute1 is 'Keyword'. However, if I set attribute1 to 'Keyword/Word' then it does not return any results. It has something to do with the forward slashes, since select xmlPath.value('(*/*[local-name()=sql:variable("attribute1")]/Word)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') does work.