# Pass a variable into a `.exist()` method?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Is there a way to pass a variable into a `.exist()` method? Here is the original code that I'm running on SQL Server Manager 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE #ExtractXML(xmldata xml)
    insert into #ExtractXML (xmldata)
    SELECT           
            CASE WHEN FormResults.XMLFormFields.exist('(/form/PalletItems/Items)[1]') = 0 then NULL 
            ELSE      FormResults.XMLFormFields.query('(/form/PalletItems/Items)[1]') END       
    FROM FormResults
    where FormTypeID = @FormTypeID
```

I would like to store this: `'(/form/PalletItems/Items)[1]'`as as variable @XMLPath varchar(100). I thought I could simply insert it like this:

```
SELECT           
            CASE WHEN FormResults.XMLFormFields.exist(@XMLPath) = 0 then NULL
            ELSE      FormResults.XMLFormFields.query(@XMLPath) END     
    FROM FormResults where FormTypeID = 1
```

but I get an error stating:  `The argument 1 of the XML data type method "exist" must be a string literal.`

Do any of you have any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server XQuery Extension Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186364.aspx)

```
DECLARE @x xml = '<A>foo</A>'

DECLARE @Xpath varchar(max) = '/A'
SELECT @x.exist('sql:variable("@Xpath")')

DECLARE @Xpaths TABLE (Xpath varchar(max))
INSERT @Xpaths VALUES ('/A')
SELECT @x.exist('sql:column("Xpath")') FROM @Xpaths
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! But do you have a recommendation of how to do this without an OPENXML?

Comment: @user3281388 this is not openxml.

Comment: This answer will always return 1 unless @Xpaths is null. It does not check for the existence of the node.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I was able to answer my question with an answer you gave on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9240960/3281388 So thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer to this question on this post by Mikael Eriksson: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240960/3281388

It was similar to what Anon had said, but it had the added local-name(). Here's my new and improved code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE #ExtractXML(xmldata xml)
    insert into #ExtractXML (xmldata)
    SELECT      
    CASE WHEN FormResults.XMLFormFields.exist('(//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@parent")])[1]') = 0 then NULL 
    ELSE      FormResults.XMLFormFields.query('(//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@parent")])[1]') END       
    FROM FormResults
```

Thanks for your help everybody!