# How to get the value of a field from XML, where the names of the fields in a variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to get the value of a field from XML, where the names of the fields in a variable, I do that(but not work):

```
declare @xml xml= '<a1>111</a1><a2>31</a2><a3>41</a3>';
declare @val  varchar(10)= 'a2';

declare @res  int;  
set @res = @xml.value('/@val[1]' , 'int');
select @res
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get SQL xml attribute value using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231411/get-sql-xml-attribute-value-using-variable).

Comment: this is work: ``` declare @xml xml= '<a1>111</a1><a2>31</a2><a3>41</a3>';
declare @val  varchar(10)= 'a2';

declare @res  int;  
set @res = @xml.value('(//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@val")])[1]' , 'int');
select @res ```